# Is it true that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_e\oplus[x,\mathfrak{g}]$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra and $(e,f,h)$ a principal $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple (see below). Let $\mathfrak{g}_e$ be the centralizer of $e$ and let $x\in f+\mathfrak{g}_e$. Is it true that
$$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_e\oplus[x,\mathfrak{g}]?$$
**Remarks.**

(i) The affine space $f+\mathfrak{g}_e$ is sometimes called the Kostant section, Kostant slice, or principal Slodowy slice. We have $f+\mathfrak{g}_e\subseteq\mathfrak{g}^{reg}$.

(ii) Since $x,e\in\mathfrak{g}^{reg}$ we have $\dim\mathfrak{g}_e+\dim[x,\mathfrak{g}]=\dim\mathfrak{g}$ so it suffices to show that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_e+[x,\mathfrak{g}]$.

(iii) When $\mathfrak{g}$ is of type $A_1$ or $A_2$, I verified by brute force that indeed $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_e\oplus[x,\mathfrak{g}]$.

---

**Definition.** A *principal $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple* in $\mathfrak{g}$ is a triple $(e,f,h)$ of elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $[h,e]=2e,[h,f]=-2f,[e,f]=h$ and $e$ is *regular*, i.e. its centralizer has dimension equal to the rank of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Something is wrong here: $e\in[x,\mathfrak g]\cap\mathfrak g_e$ for e. g. $x=f$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე No: $e\notin [f,\mathfrak{g}]$ [$:=\mathrm{Im}(ad(f))$] in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Comment: @YCor Oh yes sorry

Comment: This is one of the main reasons why Slodowy slices are studied. They are *transverse to the adjoint orbits*, meaning that if $x\in f+\mathfrak{g}_e$, then $T_x\mathfrak{g}=T_x(f+\mathfrak{g}_e)\oplus T_x(G\cdot x)$ where $G$ is the adjoint group of $\mathfrak{g}$. Under the identification $T_x\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}$, we recover the identity in question.

Comment: @SHP What confuses me is that usually one formulates this property of slices only for $x=f$. Is it stated in this form somewhere?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It is stated, for example, in Gan--Ginzburg *Quantization of Slodowy slices*, Section 2.2. But I think it goes back to Slodowy's work.

Comment: @SHP, in the case of Slodowy slices, the sum is not necessarily direct. In Gan and Ginzburg article transversality is to be understood as in diffrential geometry, that is why only surjectivity of the differential is mentionned. It is always direct at x=f by usual $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ theory. Yet, any Slodowy slice contains regular elements (as $G\cdot( f+\mathfrak{g}^e)$ is dense in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the set of regular elements is open). Hence by a dimension argument, if $e$ is not regular, the sum cannot be direct at the regular elements of the slice.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the case. To see this, filter $\mathfrak{g}$ by $Ker(ad_e^i)$. 
Let $Gr(\mathfrak{g})$ be the associated graded. We have a symbol map 
$sym : \mathfrak{g} \to Gr(\mathfrak{g})$ given by sending an element to the "leading term" w.r.t. this filtration. 
It would suffice to show that it is generated by the symbols of elements of $\mathfrak{g}_e + [x,\mathfrak{g}]$, by a standard descent argument (look at the least element not in your subspace in terms of this filtration) 
But, after passage to the associated graded, $ad_x$ acts on symbols like $ad_f$ modulo previous graded pieces. 
More precisely, we have $sym(ad_x(u)) = sym(ad_f(u))$ for every $u$. 
This shows that the image of the symbol don't change if you replace $x$ by $f$, so we can reduce to this case. But for $x = f$ the statement is a standard result on representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ with no trivial components (which follows from the triple being principal in this case).

Edit: As mensioned in the comment below, the condition on non-triviality of the representation is irrelevant here. It is just true for every $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representation.

Comment: Should not $\mathfrak g_e + [x,\mathfrak g]=\mathfrak g$ be true for any nilpotent $e$ whatsoever? I mean, $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak g_e\oplus[f,\mathfrak g]$ seems to be true even if there are trivial components.